# Find max product using divide and conqure in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to create and algorithm using divide and conquer that runs in O(n) time, it needs to find the maximum product between two numbers in an array of distinct numbers that can be positive or negative. I've been trying to use findMax and findMin to solve this but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Why divide-and-conquer?

Comment: This looks like a typical case of divide-and-don't-do-better, not divide-and-conquer. As another typical case: if you have a function max2 that gives the maximum of two elements, and you want to find the maximum of an array, you can write either `max(a[0..n]) = max2(a[0], max(a[1..n]))` (simple iterative search) or `max(a[0..n] = max2(max(a[0..n/2]), max(a[n/2..n])))` (divide-and-don't-do-better). Both approaches have the exact same complexity.

Comment: In your case, calling neg1, neg2 the two biggest negative numbers in the array and pos1, pos2 the two biggest positive numbers in the array, it's relatively obvious that the maximum product of the array is the maximum of `neg1*neg2` and `pos1*pos2`. So you can simply iterate on the array to find these four numbers and return the biggest of these two products.

Comment: @Stef, I applaud you for resisting what must have been an overwhelming urge to mention the cases where there are fewer than two positive or two negative numbers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Hahaha you read in me like in a book. The fun thing is that you don't even need to check the signs of neg1 and neg2 and pos1 and pos2, nor that {neg1, neg2} and {pos1, pos2} don't intersect; you can just take the minimum and second-minimum, and the maximum and second-maximum, so as long as the array has at least 2 elements the algorithm will work.

Comment: @ruakh I know its easier to not use divide and conquer but for this case i need to specifically use divide and conquer :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array A, this array can be split into two subarrays B and C.  The maximum product for A, is one of the following:

1. The maximum product from B
2. The maximum product from C
3. The largest positive value from B multiplied with the largest positive value from C
4. The largest negative value from B multiplied with the largest negative value from C

You have to be able to combine two subarrays in constant time:
Given max_prod_B, largest_pos_B, largest_neg_B, max_prod_C, largest_pos_C, largest_neg_C you can create (in constant time):

max_prod_A = max(max_prod_B,max_prod_C, largest_pos_B x largest_pos_C, largest_neg_B x largest_neg_C)
largest_pos_A = max(largest_pos_B,largest_pos_C)
largest_neg_A = min(largest_neg_B,largest_neg_C)

aaand ...  Done.

Comment: Which elements of A are contained in B (and hence in C)? Why not simply make a single pass through A to identify the two largest positive values (or conclude the are only 1 or 0) and identify the two smallest negative values (or conclude the are only 1 or 0)?

Comment: because then it wouldn't be a divide and conquer algorithm which OP has been tasked to solve.  any split of A is fine.